# Are questions picked up by their title?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that questions with some good title are better received. You can clearly see that in the picture below:

[image]

The post in the centre is mine. You can see that it is very well received and has a lot of answers and views and votes which are constantly increasing. But, the posts below and above which don’t have a catchy title are not well received by the community.

---

So, my concern on this is that, this is really bad for newbies. When they come, they don’t know the site so well and don’t give up good titles. So, they are not well received. Can this be prevented and we are convinced to see all the posts?

Comment: Why do you think the issue is the title and not the whole post?

Comment: @Tom Because for viewing the entire post, we need to open it. So, that given a view

Comment: Not saying that it's the case in your specific example, but clickbait is everywhere, even in Stack Overflow. And it works.

Comment: Well, [your question was on the Hot Network Question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72283809/timeline) that is shown to almost all SE sites on the right sidebar, where many visitors can only upvote but not downvote due to the association rep bonus.

Comment: But, not on meta right?

Comment: [Also on Meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j8og.png)

Comment: @AndrewT. I could find that. Where is it? I

Comment: @VLAZ but where is ny question that way? Why can't I see it?

Comment: You can see it in [the full HNQ list](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot). The side-bar gives a small selection of those questions every time you open a page. If you reload enough, you'd see it eventually but the full list is more convenient.

Comment: That said, the upvotes mostly came before HNQ, so perhaps you just hit the spot of interesting question that many wanted to answer.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want to discuss? A bad title is generally a bad feature of a question. Do you wonder how we can *make* people *view* questions despite them being bad in some way? Do you wonder how we can *prevent* people from *asking* questions that are bad in some way?

Comment: I find it increasingly tiring to see the "bad for newbies" rhetoric. Can we please stop treating new users as if they were literal babies? Some of them are folks with decades of experience who simply neglected to learn the basics of writing a good contribution. Things like writing a good title are called general education, they do not require a single speck of knowledge of how the site works.

Comment: The picture in the post shows 3 questions with *good titles*. I don't understand what that picture proves or even how those 3 posts relate to each other. Neither of the titles represent true "titles by a new user" - I would expect you refer to titles like "I m new. My code not worky. Help anyone." but examples you pick a nowhere close to that. Some [edit] would be nice to clarify why titles shown are "bad" from your point of view.

Comment: Side note - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72287231/how-to-split-an-array-of-objects-in-java-or-kotlin seem to be just trolling or some science experiment. I'm not sure how first one got so many upvotes (as I expect all sorts of "split array" variations already answered for Java at least), but posting a second one with almost identical title... is questionable.

Comment: Easy to answer questions that are well written with a decent title often get a lot of attention, because people want to help others or because they want to earn rep. Titles absolutely do affect the attention a post gets, as does the first paragraph. that's just... web 101

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The actions in the first question are questionable as well. OP provided a solution and asks for a better approach. The accepted answers does exactly the same and OP said it doesn't work, still it is accepted. It is sometimes really weird how things evolve here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: *"Because for viewing the entire post, we need to open it. So, that given a view"* But you have to open a post to vote on it.

Comment: Why hide the picture?  You can't talk about a picture without, well, actually having the picture.

Comment: No, novices will have to learn through making mistakes if they choose to just blunder ahead without informing themselves properly first. I don't really know why you particularly want to discriminate on that group of people though, it's problematic for anyone to not try their best.

Comment: @Ann Zen: Yes, statistically clickbait works. But I am sick and tired of it on YouTube. And of [shocked faces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln1qbgZz_TQ&t=14m20s).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions with an appropriate title are more likely to attract attention from people that are interested in that topic (because the title helps people know whether the question is relevant to them or not, and for older questions at least they're more likely to appear in Google search results). People who find a question interesting are presumably more likely to upvote it.

A good title may also deter people who *aren't* interested in the question from reading it (which is actually a good thing because there's no benefit to people reading irrelevant posts; they're unlikely to answer, upvote, or personally benefit from reading from the content). In fact, I don't have data to support it, but I would assume that they'd actually be more likely to downvote than to upvote (because they didn't find the content helpful).

Also, the quality of the title tends to correlate with the content of the entire post. People that put forth effort to write a good title are probably also spending more time and effort on the question as a whole (and *vice versa*).

In fact, the very first section of the How to Ask page in the help center specifically advises users to write a good title and gives some directions on how to do so (complete with 6 examples of good and bad titles), so people who write good titles are more likely to have read the help center documentation.

That being said, I don't agree that this is a bad thing. A good title is an important part of writing a good post and indicates the amount of effort they put into the post overall. If someone wrote a poor title, that means that they either didn't read "How to Ask" or they didn't apply its advice. So the root cause here is newbies not reading (or disregarding) the help center, not the fact that people dislike questions with poor titles.